# Parse Hashtable in JSON, perfect(jsonencode). But I don't know how to parse json in Hashtable(jsondecode). (Android)

Tags: android, json, hashtable, decode, encode

I've created a JSON encode where you enter a HashTable (`public Hashtable<?, ?> JSonDecode(String data) {... return objJS.toString(); }` ) and get a string in JSON format. That is:

If I have a Hashtable with this (Hashtable in Hashtable):

**Example Hashtable**:

```
Hashtable<String, Object> exampleHT = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    exampleHT.put("Color", "Red");
    exampleHT.put("OtherKey", "OtherValue");
    exampleHT.put("OtherKey2", "OtherValue2");

Hashtable<String, Object> country = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    country.put("Spain", "Madrid");
    country.put("France","Paris");
    country.put("Italy", "Rome");

Hashtable<String, String> pokemon = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    pokemon.put("Pikachu", "Electric");
    pokemon.put("Charmander","Fire");

country.put("Pokemons", pokemon);

exampleHT.put("Countries", country);
```

I use my function(`JSonEncode(exampleHT);`) and I get this string:

```
{
    "Color":"Red",
    "Countries":{
        "Spain":"Madrid",
        "France":"Paris",
        "Italy":"Rome",
        "Pokemons":{
            "Pikachu":"Electric",
            "Charmander":"Fire"
        }
    },
    "OtherKey":"OtherValue",
    "OtherKey2":"OtherValue2"
}
```

**It works perfectly! My problem is to create the reverse process, with *JSonDecode*.**

```
Hashtable<?, ?> hashUnknown = JSonDecode(jsonStringExample);

public Hashtable<?, ?> JSonDecode(String data) {
 // I do not know how to parse json in Hashtable, without indicating the tags manually.
```

}

I do not know how to parse json in Hashtable, without indicating the tags manually.
That is, without it:

```
JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray (jObject.getString ("Color"));
JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray (jObject.getString ("Countries"));
```

This should be dynamic without knowing json content without writing manually Color, Countries, ....

Any ideas or advice? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can get an Iterator object (java.util.Iterator) over the keys of your JSONObject (jObject)
So you can write something like this:

```
Iterator<String> it = jObject.keys();
String key = null;
Object value = null;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    key = it.next();
    value = jObject.get(key);
    // Then test the instance of the value variable
    // and perform some logic
}
```